# How to get total number of document in Solr without returning everything?

Tags: php, solr

One way to know how many document are there in total is:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/demo/select?indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json`

The `response->numFound` will be the number of document. However, this will return all the data in Solr too. This will be very slow if I have many document or if I have some very big document. Is there quicker way to do counting? Something like `select count(*) from table` in SQL?

P.S. I am using PHP to connect to Solr.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just append `&rows=0` to your query.